# How to add a header in a .txt file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add a permanent header for a text file and along with the headers there should be the corresponding information i.e:

My code snippet:

```
name = input ("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
BirthYear = input("Birth Year: ")

file = open ("info.txt", "a")
file.write ("Name Age Grade\n")
file.write ("{} / {} / {}\n".format(name, age, birthYear))
file.close()
```

So far the code just outputs the following into a text file :

```
Name Age BirthYear
name / 16 / 1999
```

the header is not permanently on the top of the page. The corresponding information of each header should align to the headers;
I would like it to look something like the following:

```
Name    Age  BirthYear  
Sam     22   1993
Bob     21   1992
```

it has to be in a text file.

Comment: use the `csv` module

Comment: Can you show more code? Is this happening in a loop? Or, are you appending to existing file?  More context would be helpful...

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly?  You need the data in a text file to align visually?

Comment: @saarrrr Yes, it has to be aligned proprerly in the text file.

Comment: @DavidZemens This is a general idea, just wanted to see how to get a headline into the text file and store the information into ordered columns and rows. And the code creates a text file for you after running the code.

Comment: Yes I just don't see anything in this code that would put the header string anywhere *but* the first row, unless you're appending to an existing file.  In which case you should check for the presence of the header, and only write it if it's not already there.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, I am appending an existing file however there should be a header of titles at the very top of the text file ensuring the information under it is corresponding to the title.

Comment: I down graded the question for being too vague.

Answer (score 4):

What about just opening the file and writing in the header and then using a new with block to loop through and write in the individual records? I came across your question as I also needed to print a header into my csv text file. Eventually I just did the following (using your example):

```
header = "Name, Age, BirthYear"

with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(header + "\n")
    f.close

with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:

    for x in rows_sub:
        f.write(str(x) + ", " + c + "\n") #the line I needed to have printed via a loop
```

Answer (score 3):

text files do not have a header.  If you want a true header, you'll need a more complex format.  Alternatively, if you just need something that acts like a header, then you need to figure out how many characters fit on your page vertically, and print the header every N lines.

For horizontal alignment, make use of the extra tokens you can use with `format()`.  As an example:

```
>>> print('{a:^8}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a='this', b='that', c='other'))
  this    that   other
```

where `^8` says I want the string centered across 8 characters.  Obviously you have to choose (or derive) the value that works for your data.

Comment: I think this is close to what he needs, to be 100% sure you are aligned, you will need to aggregate your data first and find the longest entries in each column so you can calculate the remaining or needed space buffer.

Comment: Naturally, it was just an example, but thanks for the reminder that the OP might not necessarily understand the implications.  I've added a line to say it's not meant to be the exact solution to OPs algorithm.

Comment: OK, great this isn't really what I was expecting. in terms of making it perfectly align I can do but just having a header of the titles at the top of the text file when i want to view them is what I was looking for. so basically when i want to append the file the header is still there.

Comment: @MisterBob  I'm not sure I understand what the header problem is, then.  Can you add more detail to your question?  Appending to a file does not delete what was there before.  If the file is empty, write the header.  If not, just continue with normal appending.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the header row already exists, write it in to the file if it doesn't exist in the first line.

```
name = input ("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
BirthYear = input("Birth Year: ")
filename = "info.txt"
header = "Name Age Grade\n"

def WriteHeader(filename, header):
    """
    ;param filename: a file path
    ;param header: a string representing the file's "header" row

    This function will check if the header exists in the first line
    and inserts the header if it doesn't exist
    """
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = [line for line in file]
    file.close()
    if lines and lines[0] == header:
        # There are some lines in the file, and first line is the header
        return True
    else:
        # The first line is NOT the header
        file = open(filename, w)
        # Rewrite the file: append header if needed, and all lines which previously were there
        # excluding any misplaced header lines which were not at row 1
        file.write(header + ''.join([line for line in lines if not line == header]))
        file.close()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if WriteHeader(filename, header):
        file = open(filename, 'a')
        file.write("{} / {} / {}\n".format(name, age, BirthYear))
        file.close()
    else:
        print 'there was some problems...'
```

On second thought, this is simpler:

```
def WriteHeader2(filename, header):
    # Always writes the header.
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    # remove any matching 'header' from the file, in case ther are duplicate header rows in the wrong places
    lines = [line for line in file if not line == header]
    file.close()

    # rewrite the file, appending the header to row 1
    file = open(filename, w)
    file.write(''.join([line for line in lines].insert(0,header))    
    file.close()
```

Comment: Oh i see, i will try this.

Comment: if lines[0] == header:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If `lines` is an empty list you'll have to account for that...  try `if lines and lines[0] == header:`

Comment: OMG, thanks so much David, this is great, how on earth did you even manage to think of this Thanks again. nah seriously this works 100%

Comment: Cheers -- do consider marking this as "accepted" if it's helped with your problem :)  The solution comes to me because of experience with the various states of a file-like object, while you initially have it open in 'append' mode, you can't read from it, so you have to first open it in 'read' mode so you can examine its contents, and then re-open in 'write' or 'append' mode to process the file accordingly based on whether your header row exists or not.